# Scala 2.8: how to initialize child class

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Consider the following code:

```
abstract class X {
  def a:Unit
  a
}

class Y extends X {
  var s:String = "Hello"
  def a:Unit = println ("String is "+s)
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
scala> new Y
String is null
res6: Y = Y@18aeabe
```

How can I get the parent class `X` to wait for `s` to be initialized when calling `a`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parent's fields and the parent constructor are always initialized and run before the children's field and constructor. It means that the call to `a` happens before your `var s` is set in the child class.

In general, it's a bad idea to call a virtual method from a constructor; C++ even disallows it (or, rather than disallowing it, doesn't call the method implemented in the child class when called from the superclass's constructor).

However, you can fix it if you turn your `var s` in `class Y` into a `lazy val` or a `def` instead. `lazy val`s are initialized the first time their value is accessed, no matter by whom; `def`s pose no initialization issues like `var`s or `val`s. However, be careful not to call any other uninitialized structure from within the implementation of `a`, as the same problem will show up again.

**Edit:**

You can also use Scala's “early definitions” (or early initialization) feature:

```
class Y extends {
  var s = "Hello"
} with X {
  def a: Unit = println ("String is "+s)
}
```

Comment: I need `s` to be a `var` as it is modified later on in my code. Thus, both `def` and `val` won't work.

Comment: Thanks. The early definition feature is interesting.

Comment: Can you take a step back and say more about what you're trying to do, not how you're trying to do it?

Comment: @rshallit: Its a bit complicated. Basically, I want the child class to define a function that is called at init of the parent class. The function accesses some variables in the child class.

Comment: Why does Scala not support `lazy var` ?

Comment: There's a discussion of that [here](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/lazy-var-td1943810.html).